# How to open cmd and run a batch file in it in one command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, java

I'm making a program which runs C++ using G++ and to build/run it, it creates a .bat file which should then be ran in a new cmd window. From Java, I can run commands, but just running a command doesn't open cmd, so I need to open cmd and also run a command *in* that cmd window in one command. How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried?  It should be as simple as running the batch file within the command prompt.

Comment: As I'm using Java, I need to run cmd and a command in cmd, both in the same line. I've tried `cmd -c <batch file path>` or something along those lines.

Comment: reach a .bat file then run that.  The output of all commands, will remain in the single command prompt window, which seems to fit what you want.  If it does not then provide specific examples of what you actually do want.

Comment: Do you mean like having a .bat file which opens cmd then runs a command? Because if I just run a .bat file from Java, it doesn't actually open cmd.

Comment: This is really a programming question and should be asked on [so]

Comment: You should also read [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) - Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program. It tells you exactly what arguments you can pass to `cmd`. Hint `-c` isn't one of them.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, that worked. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @ZacGarby Answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I run `cmd` and execute a batch file

> From Java, I can run commands, but just running a command doesn't open cmd, so I need to open cmd and also run a command in that cmd window in one command.
>
> How do I do this?

From your Java program use the following:

```
cmd /c batch.cmd
```

This will start a new `cmd` shell, run `batch.cmd` and then terminate the shell. See [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) for more information.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) - Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.